# After upgrading to 17.10 it takes 1 minute to start sometimes more than 1 minute.

Tags: boot, upgrade, malware

1-After upgrading the system totally became slow. It takes more time to load files even to open files it takes 10 to 20 seconds. How can I solve this issue?
2- When I start it shows your PC at risk.

Comment: Who says that your PC is at risk? Whoever it is should give a link to further information. As long as you don't give more details, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: I have installed MAVL, (mcafee anti virus for Linux. unfortunately I am not able to run the anti virus). This is the software which shows PC at risk. So I thought I am not able to run the software but there is one issue.